# Revert Sharepoint back to default install

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, design

I installed foundation on my machine a few months back and fooled around with branding and such. I am curious if there is a way to revert share point back to the default styles. Some of the things that got messed up was the core layout of the master page (no back up was made), core styles, bootstrap was implemented and so on and so forth.

My manager had me go through this so I could learn how to restore share point back to its default look and feel.

Is this possible?

Comment: There are copies of the standard OOTB master pages out there, just deploy that and change the master page of the back-end to point to this newly deployed one.

Comment: Could you point me to some? I'm not really sure where I would begin to look for this stuff.

Comment: http://tommdaly.wordpress.com/2011/10/18/clean-v4-master-page/ - Note: I'm assuming you're using 2010 here.

Answer (score 1):

If there is nothing you need to save from your exploring tasks, then I'd simply delete the web applications in Central Administration, and create new ones. Then you can create new web applications, site collections and sites again with default style, provided that you havn't installed a package on your farm.